# Exporting an array of mutations inside mutations.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm using [`vuexfire`](https://github.com/posva/vuexfire) to bind my `vuex` state to firebase, and to do that, I need to put their `{ firebaseMutations }` in the mutations for the store. My mutations are in a `mutations.js` file, however. I tried exporting the mutations like this:

```
export { firebaseMutations } from 'vuexfire'
```

but this error comes up : `Uncaught Error: [vuex] mutations should be function but "mutations.firebaseMutations" is {}.`

I've tried many variations of

```
export * from { firebaseMutations }
```

but none of them work.

Is there a way I can either use the object spread operator or `export` to export these from my `mutations.js`?

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import * as actions from './actions'
import * as getters from './getters'
import * as mutations from './mutations'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    // ...
  },
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions,
  strict: debug
})
```

Comment: Seems like you should be importing not exporting

Comment: I want to export it from my `mutations.js`. Does importing it work?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Why do you want to export `firebaseMutations`? What are you trying to accomplish? If you're trying to include the `firebaseMutations` in your project, you'd want to import them and add them to your mutations like the documentation you linked says to do.

Comment: I can't do that because my mutations are external.

Comment: I don't know what that means. Can you share your code?

Comment: Alright, I did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155098/discussion-between-thanksd-and-thetechnokid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using the object spread operator on both:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import * as actions from './actions'
import * as getters from './getters'
import * as mutations from './mutations'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    // ...
  },
  getters,
  mutations: {
     ...mutations,
     ...firebaseMutations
  },
  actions,
  strict: debug
})
```

Comment: and how did you define `firebaseMutations` ?